# Cant input in vscode while debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

i am not able to input while debugging a cpp code in vs code 
and i tried to find runinterminal command in vs code setting but i was unsuccessfull
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: i cant find runinterminal checkbox